# how to allow empty jdateChooser

Tags: java, ms-access-2007

I want to save two dates in MS Access from two jDateChoosers.
It works fine with both jDateChoosers completed, but not if one of them is empty.
How to save data into database when jDateChooser ramains empty.

```
    java.sql.Date
    sqldate1=new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser1.getDate().getTime());
    java.sql.Date
    sqldate2=new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser2.getDate().getTime());


    String sql = "insert into date_insert (date1, date2) "
                + "values ('"+sqldate1+"','"+sqldate2+"') ";
```

In MS Access date fields are set as No for required